# How to reference DOM in Firefox extension popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I am trying to reference the DOM in this Firefox popup so that I can change the value of it:

[image]

But i'm not too sure on how to go about that. I have tried Jquery and Document references, but they do not work.

```
<body>
<div id="walrusContainer">hello</span>
<script id="modalScript"></script>
</body>
```

I am trying to reference the "walrusContainer" in the popup.

**edit**

[image]

That is what I have attempted in trying to reference the *'modalScript'* script and changing its src. This did not work, along with the *'walrusContainer'* `div` where `$('#walrusContainer').text('change')` didn't work either.

Comment: hi, show what you have tried. For example with jquery you can use $('#walrusContainer') to reference your div

Comment: Hello, I have tried calling $('#walrusContainer') in js, and also document.getElementById('walrusContainer') in the console. So far, the DOM can't seem to figure out where to find the div.

Comment: OK show us in your question the entire js code,

Comment: I have added an image to the edit

Comment: You have errors in your code. you have an open div but you close it with a span. <div id="walrusContainer">hello</div> and with jquery $('#walrusContainer').text('new text'); But, please, don't post code as image!!!

Comment: I fixed the error but it still does not change the text. My bad with the photo, first timer here :[